# How to change mysql mode via php by .cnf file?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to change mysql mode via php by .cnf file but php ignore it.

**my.cnf File**

```
[mysqld]
sql-mode= "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION;"
```

**php File**

```
<? php
require "connect.php";
session_start();
$settings = parse_ini_file('my.cnf',true);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change mysql mode via PDO in PHP :

```
$pdo = new PDO(
 $dsn, 
 $username, 
 $password, 
 array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET sql_mode="TRADITIONAL"') 
);
```

Comment: what do you mean by dsn variable ?

Comment: `"mysql:dbname=$db;host=$host"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want change the ymy.cnf setting contente remember that you should restart the db engine for see the effects
otherwise  if you want change your mysql sqlmode runtime  you should use a query  eg if you are connecting using mysqli db driver:

```
 mysqli_query($conn, "SET SESSION sql_mode = 'YOUR SQL MODE SETTING'");
```

Comment: It doesn't work ((( mysqli_query($db, "SET SESSION sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'");
)))